# "Prime" fusion rings

Tags: rt.representation-theory, fusion-categories

Surely this concept is known! (But I don't recall seeing it - maybe under another name? But "prime" is the obvious name choice.)
Example. Open the Gepner/Kapustin paper at http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9410089. Let $F$ be the Fibonacci category and $O$ the other :-) (Table 1). The fusion rules are $e*e=e,e*g=g,g*g=e+g$ and $E*E=E,E*M=M,M*M=E$ respectively (m "minus one", g "golden"). Now you can simply take the direct products $O\bigotimes{O}$, $O\bigotimes{F}$, $F\bigotimes{F}$ by multiplying pairs of irreps, for example: $<g,M>*<g,E>=<e,M>+<g,M>$ The result are entries 1,2,3 of Table 3.
Some questions.
1. $O\in{}SU(2)_1, F\in{}SU(2)_3/Z_2$. (Read $\in$ as "realized by".) Entries 1 and 3 above are "squares" of these values as expected, but entry 2 is $SU(2)_3$. I assume this is isomorph (or whatchacallit) to $SU(2)_1\bigotimes{SU(2)_3/Z_2}$?
2. The classification of fusion rings throws a lot around with Galois groups (of whatever :-). I assume these Galois groups are also direct products?
3. More important (but just for me :-). Are the 6j symbols (or better: the F symbols) also simple products $6j(aA,bB,...)=6j(a,b...)*6j(A,B,...)$? This would probably be true (modulo quantum dimension fudge factors) if the direct product of two unitary matrices is unitary again. (I came up with this question yesterday in a night without sleep and couldn't check this property in my head :-)

If all the above makes sense, it wouldn't be necessary to consider "composite" fusion rings in the classification, and you could simply do that by not considering "composite" Galois groups. (A reference where this all is handled suffices as answer.)

Comment: After reading Höhns webpage on modular categories etc. - yes, the concept "prime" seems to be known.